# How to add Diameter Device-Watchdog Request (DWR) to log

Tags: go, prometheus, diameter-protocol

I have a simple diameter server and client app that takes from the go-diameter pkg example (https://github.com/fiorix/go-diameter). The Wireshark can capture Device-Watchdog requests and answers smoothly as you see below

[image]

but, how to make the server log the Device-watchdog parameters ? and create Prometheus metric for it?